# How to query Pom version using maven

Tags: maven-2, pom.xml

Is there a goal one can execute that will just echo the version of a pom?  I can think of a way to make it work using the maven-ant-plugin, but that requires me to have ant-plugin configuration in the pom and I would like a method that would work with any pom.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version
```

If you want *just* the version echoed, and not the rest of the Maven "noise", you would use

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout
```